# Detect curl useragent in php

Tags: php, user-agent

I'm using this script to detect curl in a php page but it doesen't work... I always get "curl ua"

```
if ($usera = "curl")
   echo "curl ua";
else 
   echo "no curl";

?>
```

Comment: that's because you are using an assignment, not a comparison

Comment: and also note that this will work if you are the one making the cURL call and you know that's the user agent.. because anyone else can set any other user agent

Comment: use == instead of = !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The exact curl user-agent string will be different based on version. For example this one:

```
curl/7.15.1 (i386-pc-win32) libcurl/7.15.1 OpenSSL/0.9.8a zlib/1.2.3
```

So what you can do is, check whether the `curl` or `libcurl` is existed in the agent string or not.

```
if(preg_match("/curl|libcurl/", $usera)){
    // do something ...
}
```

But if the `curl` client change the `Agent String`, then you'll not be able to detect it. For example with below `curl` request I am changing the user agent into `Opera 9.0`

```
curl -A "Opera 9.0" http://www.example.com/
```

Comment: I was tryng to do something like this http://valentines.digitalocean.com/ Thanks!

Comment: The regex is redundant because if it matches 'curl', it matches also 'libcurl'. I'd add instead 'cURL' to match for ex. `PycURL/7.15.5`

Answer (score 0):

The Useragent could be changed by user, but default settings could be recognized by:

```
function is_curl() {
    if (stristr($_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"], 'curl'))
        return true;
}
```